# Given a string of 10 digits what is the chance of a random 10 digit string matching with an edit distance of 2

Tags: probability, string-count

Given a string of 10 random digits in the range 0-9 what is the probability of another random 10 digit string (in the same range) matching where a match can have an edit distance of 2.

By edit distance I mean that a string could be said to match if you could arrive at the correct answer by making two edits. For example for the string:

1111111111

The string 1111111142 would be considered a match as by editing the last two numbers it is possible to get the correct sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chance of any given digit matching is 1/10 and not matching is 9/10.

For *exactly* 2 edits, you need 8 matches, 2 non-matches, and there are 10 choose 2 ways to arrange those.  So $P={\frac{1}{10}}^8 \cdot {\frac{9}{10}}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{2} \approx3.6 \cdot 10^{-7}$

For 2 or fewer you would add the less likely 1 and 0 terms to get about $3.7 \cdot 10^{-7}$

Of course this assumes all random digits in each string are independent of one another.

Comment: I'm using the formula you gave me but I have realized that I am unclear on the $c= \frac{10}{2}$ term. Would you be able to give more detail on it. 

I am using the formula to calculate the probability when allowing 5 edits would it be
$P=\frac{1}{10}^5\cdot\frac{9}{10}^5\cdot(\frac{10}{5})$

Comment: Sorry HAL!  Are you familiar with choose notation?  In the chase of $10\choose2$ it's $\frac{10!}{2!\cdot (10-2)!}=45$.  For $10\choose{5}$, $\frac{10!}{5! 5!}=252$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination